# Is it possible a post-doc position for a specialist in medicine without PhD?

Tags: phd, postdocs, medicine

I graduated from Medical Faculty ten years ago. I got my degree as a Microbiology Specialist in 2015. I have been working as a Clinical Microbiologist in a hospital since then. I completed all my education and working in Turkey.

Last month, I attended a conference. I met a professor from King's College London. After discussing some issues about bacterial interactions this professor offered me a postdoc position in his department. I want to accept this position but I don't have a Ph.D. degree. The professor also doesn't sure and he advised me to search this issue.

Does anyone know if it is possible or can you address me an organization to ask this question?

Comment: It's very strange that the professor would ask *you* to find this out.  It depends entirely on the rules of his institution, and so he's the one best placed to talk to administrators and find the answer.  But even if it's not allowed to hire you as a postdoc, it may be possible to hire you with some other job title instead - and it's the professor who would have to make the decision as to whether to do that.

Comment: What @NateEldredge said, but also note that many of the positions that are colloquial described as "postdocs" do not actually mention doctoral status in the formal job title (often Research Associate or some such). Not everybody in academia has a PhD, although anecdotally those without are becoming rarer.

Comment: There is a significant chance that they could hire you as something like a "research scientist", "assistant researcher", etc, instead of using the inappropriate "postdoc" title. It is actually up to the University/department as to how the professor can use their funds. So long as the funds aren't specifically required to be only used specifically for a "postdoc", they can probably hire you as staff on a contract basis.

Answer (score 5):

The organization to ask is the organization that wants to employ you. The name postdoc suggest that a postdoc starts after you became a doctor, but there is often some leeway in interpreting those rules. However, how much leeway depends a lot on the specific country and institution. Even within institutions departments can differ quite a lot in the extend to which they are willing to make use of the leeway offered by the rules set at the higher levels. So the only advise we can give you is to talk to HR department of the university that wants to hire you.